# HSQL execute condition LIKE ANY

Tags: sql, hsqldb

I'm trying to execute an SQL statement, with a where clause that does something like:

```
WHERE col LIKE ANY (values...)
```

According to the [HSQLDB documentation](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch09.html) it *seems* to me that I should be able to do it:

```
condition
       { ...
      | value [NOT] LIKE value [ESCAPE] value }

value
       [+ | -] { term [{ + | - | * | / | || } term]
      | ( condition )
      | function ( [parameter] [,...] )
      | selectStatement giving one value
      | {ANY|ALL} (selectStatement giving single column)
```

However, this does not seem to work.

I can execute this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE (selectStatement giving 1 column with single value)
```

But any of these will give me an error:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE (selectStatement giving 1 column with multiple values) 
 -> cardinality violation


SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE ANY (selectStatement giving 1 column with single value) 
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE ANY (selectStatement giving 1 column with multiple values) 
 -> unexpected token: SELECT
```

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong? 
Is this not supported, or am I misunderstanding the documentation?

Thanks!

Comment: Note the comment in the guide page you linked "This Guide is for HSQLDB version 1.8.0. For the latest version see HSQLDB version 2.x Guide.". The specifications in 1.8.0 guide were poorly written and cannot be relied on.

Comment: ... I feel like an idiot for not noticing that. Thank you! Turns out it is not possible after all, according to the 2.x guide. I guess I'm stuck with making some custom SQL function. Thanks though, I was really banging my head at this wondering why it didn't work!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to achieve, you can use the following:

This query uses the value returned by the subquery for LIKE comparison. The value normally has a escape character, for example `super%`, which matches all words beginning with `super`:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE (selectStatement giving 1 column with single value)
```

This query uses the values returned by the subquery as a list. Each of the list values is compared to the col value and when the first exact match is found, the result is true. This type of query is used to return a subset of the rows from the table that have a value that is in the list returned by the subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE col = ANY (selectStatement giving 1 column with multiple values)
```

Comment: Thanks, though for this case I really needed to use ANY with the % operator, since I need to filter for all strings starting with the selected values, so '=' simply won't do here unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I am late to the game here, but would like to add the idea of a colleague of mine to use EXISTS() to allow multiple LIKE/ILIKE conditions.

So that query simulates the "x LIKE ANY('{}')"

```
SELECT
    tables.table_name
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    EXISTS(SELECT *
           FROM
               UNNEST (ARRAY['a%', 'b%', 'c%']) AS t(like_value)
           WHERE
               LOWER(tables.table_name) LIKE LOWER(like_value))
ORDER BY
    tables.table_name
```

is equivalent to that in Postgresql

```
SELECT
    tables.table_name
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    tables.table_name ILIKE ANY ('{a%, b%, c%}')
ORDER BY
    tables.table_name
```

Additionally, if you would like to use that from Java using prepared statements and to prevent Hsqldb from throwing a "General error" you have to cast the placeholder like so:

```
SELECT
    tables.table_name
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    EXISTS(SELECT *
           FROM
               UNNEST (CAST(? as VARCHAR(2048) ARRAY)) AS t(like_value)
           WHERE
               LOWER(tables.table_name) LIKE LOWER(like_value))
ORDER BY
    tables.table_name
```